# Why are all the DC biasing sources assumed as ground in BJT transistor h-parameter equivalent model?

Tags: transistors, amplifier, bias

For example consider the first image on this schematic:

[image: Schematics: typical common emitter on the left; AC equivalent showing Vcc now equal to ground on the right]

Source: http://www.zen22142.zen.co.uk/Theory/tr_model.htm.

Vcc is assumed as ground for ac equivalent circuit and thus RB1 and RB2 becomes parallel. And effective input impedance is calculated in this way. Then things like filter capacitor value are calculated using that resultant impedance.

How can this be, as the end of RB1 is not grounded but connected to Vcc? RB1 and RB2 are not really parallel here. Impedance felt by AC input current will be different than RB1 and RB2 parallel, isn't it?

Comment: No, the impedance to an AC small signal disturbance (of the resistor network) will be exactly RB1 and RB2 in parallel.  They are absolutely in parallel for AC analysis.  Think about (or calculate) the delta in current that the AC source would supply for the case when they are in parallel and the case when there is a DC source connected.

Answer (score 4):

For small-signal analysis the transistor is represented by a *linearized* small-signal model. The linearization is done for a certain operating point and excursions around that operating point are analyzed.

Since the whole circuit is linear superposition can be used. Only one source at a time is considered and then the results are added. Fixed DC don't generate any changes, therefore their contribution is zero. It is sufficient to only consider the AC source.

Answer (score 1):

For small-signal analysis all DC sources are the same as ground.  That's because for this type of analysis you are linearizing a non-linear system around some operating point set by the DC bias.  So the small-signal model only considers small perturbations around the operating point, and ideal DC sources do not change with the perturbations meaning they are effectively AC ground.

Comment: John D and @Mario thanks for your responses. Sorry for not elaborating my problem before. I've stated the problem I'm facing in details in my question. Please explain it.

Answer (score 0):

A DC supply normally has very low internal resistance so an AC signal sees it as a short circuit.

Comment: We also use Bypass Caps between VDD and GND, right at the active devices, to better approximate the goal of VDD does not move. A power supply, two meters away, has 4 uHenry inductance in the power wiring, which is 25 ohms at 1MHz.